# How many installs of Emacs do I have?

Tags: applications, filesystem

At the zsh, I enter `which emacs` and get `/usr/local/bin/emacs`.

In my `/Applications` folder, I have an application called `Emacs`.  When I click `get info` it says that it resides at `/Applications`.

So that all makes me think I have two different installs.

But then I moved the one in `/Applications` to the Trash and then tried running `emacs` and `/usr/local/bin/emacs` from the command line.  Both times, I was met with `zsh: command not found: emacs`.

So that makes it seem like there is only one install.

What am I missing here?

Comment: There might be even one in `/usr/bin`:-) How did you install `/usr/local/bin/emacs`?

Comment: hell if I know!  Sometimes I use `brew cask`...could that be relevant?

Comment: nope, no emacs in `/usr/bin`

Comment: Ah right, got removed in Catalina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install Emacs via `homebrew` it installs both to `/usr/local/bin` and to `/Applications`.

```
$ ll -d /usr/local/bin/emacs /Applications/Emacs.app
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root     admin  34 Jan 12  2019 /Applications/Emacs.app@ -> /usr/local/opt/emacs-mac/Emacs.app
lrwxr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  50 Mar 27 20:02 /usr/local/bin/emacs@ -> ../Cellar/emacs-mac/emacs-26.3-z-mac-7.9/bin/emacs
```